# When value is negative, subtract result from previous value

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a dataset that logically shouldn't have any negative values, but because of revisions to the data, it sometimes does. To adjust for this, I want to distribute negative values to the previous day's data.

For example, I'd like the values to change like so:

| Old | New |
| --- | --- |
| 18 | 18 |
| 12 | 10 |
| 1 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 |
| -3 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 |

I'm trying to do this programmatically in R, but haven't been able to make it work.

Here's my latest attempt, which kinda works, but only partially and feels unstable:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

# Data
nums <- as_tibble(list(
  value = c(18, 12, 1, 0, 0, -3, 1, 0, 0 ),
  date = c("2022-01-01","2022-01-02","2022-01-03",
           "2022-01-04","2022-01-05","2022-01-06",
           "2022-01-07","2022-01-08","2022-01-09"))) |> 
  mutate(date = ymd(date)) %>%
  select(date,value)

# Remove negatives
no_negs <- nums |> 
  arrange(desc(date)) |> 
  mutate(neww = if_else(lag(value,1) < 0, value + lag(value,1),value)) |>
  arrange(date) |> 
  mutate(neww = ifelse(is.na(neww), 0, neww))
```

Any thoughts on whether this is possible, and if so, how?

Thanks!

Edit: new example data

Comment: ` new <- pmax(old, 0)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Edits*: reduction of code, fix for consecutive zeroes, use second data set, general improvement.

---

We can `Reduce` it:

```r
nums1 %>%
  mutate(
    add = Reduce(function(prev, this) min(this+prev, 0),
                 value, init = 0, accumulate = TRUE, right = TRUE)[-1], 
    value2 = pmax(value + add, 0)
  ) %>%
  select(-add)
# # A tibble: 6 x 3
#   date       value value2
#   <date>     <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1 2022-01-01    18     18
# 2 2022-01-02    12      5
# 3 2022-01-03    -3      0
# 4 2022-01-04    -4      0
# 5 2022-01-05     5      3
# 6 2022-01-06    -2      0
```

and the second dataset with more consecutive zeroes:

```r
nums2 %>%
  mutate(
    add = Reduce(function(prev, this) min(this+prev, 0),
                 value, init = 0, accumulate = TRUE, right = TRUE)[-1], 
    value2 = pmax(value + add, 0)
  ) %>%
  select(-add)
# # A tibble: 9 x 3
#   date       value value2
#   <date>     <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1 2022-01-01    18     18
# 2 2022-01-02    12     10
# 3 2022-01-03     1      0
# 4 2022-01-04     0      0
# 5 2022-01-05     0      0
# 6 2022-01-06    -3      0
# 7 2022-01-07     1      1
# 8 2022-01-08     0      0
# 9 2022-01-09     0      0
```

---

Data

```r
nums1 <- structure(list(date = structure(c(18993, 18994, 18995, 18996, 18997, 18998), class = "Date"), value = c(18, 12, -3, -4, 5, -2)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
nums2 <- structure(list(date = structure(c(18993, 18994, 18995, 18996, 18997, 18998, 18999, 19000, 19001), class = "Date"), value = c(18, 12, 1, 0, 0, -3, 1, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: You could use `.dir = "backward"` in `accumulate` `nums %>% mutate(value2 = (value + accumulate(value, ~ if(.x >=0) 0 else .x + .y, .init = 0, .dir = "backward" )[-1]) * (value > 0))`

Comment: I like the `*(value>0)` trick, nice. While that is code-golf shorter, I think I'll keep the answer as-is so the OP can opt to look at `add` more easily and optimize/shorten the code later. Thanks akrun!

Comment: @r2evans-GONAVYBEATARMY 's solution works well, but seems to struggle with consecutive zeroes. For example, with this data: `nums <- as_tibble(list(
  value = c(18, 12, 1, 0, 0, -3, 1, 0, 0 ),
  date = c("2022-01-01","2022-01-02","2022-01-03",
           "2022-01-04","2022-01-05","2022-01-06",
           "2022-01-07","2022-01-08","2022-01-09"))) |> 
  mutate(date = ymd(date)) %>%
  select(date,value)`

Comment: @akrun, if I had done just a little more effort, I would have remembered that `base::Reduce` also can do reverse internally via the `right=TRUE` arg. Argh.